# How can we do integration php with virtualpost?

Tags: php

I have just discovered the virtualpost (vpos) https://code.google.com/p/vpos4php/.

I want to demonstrate with this.But I couldnt understand how it works.And also postnet.php occurs some errors."Warning: require_once(/library/Dahius/VirtualPos/Loader.php): failed to open stream:"

Can you help achiving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong path `/library/Dahius/VirtualPos/Loader.php` try adding a dot at the begin of it, if the file you're using include it is on the same folder.

Comment: This is true path.Nothing wrong with this.I assume this error about working on local.Is it possible?

Comment: you made the path on the root folder of your server? `ls -la /library`

Comment: Iam working at windows os.And Iam using wampserver manager.And there is no problem www root.

Comment: then the folder path is wrong, use the full path such as `C:/your_app_folder/library/Dahius/VirtualPos/Loader.php`

Comment: ok. Now These error has been occured.
Fatal error: Class 'Dahius_VirtualPos_Exception' not found in C:\wamp\www\vpos\library\Dahius\VirtualPos\Loader.php on line 44

Comment: use / instead of \ and check the file `Loader.php` to see if it does any includes and have the right path.

Comment: I changed '/' with '\' but it couldt solve my problem.

Comment: The error is pretty clear something is missing on the library, check if any other files include files and if their path are right.